# expand the size of EBS volume in EC2 of AWS (Centos 6.3)

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos6, amazon-ebs

I have a Linux Centos instance with the following volume partitions:

/ - 5 GB
/logs - /2 GB
/data - 4 TB (4 volumes, each 1 TB).

I would like to add more disk space (3 TB = 3 X 1TB volume) to my /data partition.

any suggestions what is the best way to do it?
Thanks!
Dotan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use LVM that shouldn't be a problem - just add more EBS volumes to your instance, add them as new PVs to your volumegroup, extend your logical volume and then resize your filesystem.
If you are using xfs you can do this online by using "xfs_growfs". If you are on ext3/4 you have to use "resize2fs"